# library (.so) with root privilege

Tags: c++, c, linux, root

I have a C++ program that uses some C libraries. The program is executed as an "unprivileged" user but one and only one function of a library (.so) loaded by the program need root privileges (it needs to write to /dev/mem).

Do exists a way to have only that function or only that library executed as root, leaving all the rest code "unprivileged"?

Thanks to all,
Cristian

Comment: No. Privileges are per-process.

Comment: I do not think so, and that would be huge security breach. Only way I know is suid app.

Comment: I agree with the security issue, but the alternative at this moment is to execute the whole program as root, with the consequent security problems (I can't check for security holes in the whole library sources)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start the program as root and open /dev/mem as a file. Then change user id to something less intrusive.  The file will keep its original permissions.

Comment: Oh, good tip, I learnt something new, thanks! At this moment I can't do this because /dev/mem is opened everytime function is called an not once at startup. But I can try to propose a modification to the function developer.

Answer (score 2):

The quick answer is **NO**.  You cannot switch userids on a per-library basis, as the user identity is a per-process property (you should know at least this, if you are trying to dig into the `/dev/mem` device).

Runtime library loading is a library task (it is done by a shared object called the dynamic loader, `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`, in my system) and it is done at runtime, so no privileged access can be granted to it, for security reasons.

Anyway, the setuid property for a program allows you to switch privileges between the *effective* user (this is the setuid user) and the *real* user (the user who executes the program) and back, so in the special case of the `root` account, you can use it to access `/dev/mem`.

Anyway, apart of the access problem, writing to `/dev/mem` is very dangerous, as it maps to the physical address space of the machine (so, it's there as physical pages, from different processes and the kernel, with no apparent order).  This has to be done with the translation table available, as pages come and go to swap in a very dynamic way.  And you are touching kernel memory anyway, so you have to extreme care when writing there.  I don't know what do you want to do, but you had better to think twice before writing there (as from your question, you don't know a process' properties well enough, it's most probable you don't know also the virtual to physical translation of pages that is being held in the kernel).

But if you want to crash your system, this is the perfect way to do.  Anyway, if that is the target you pursue, then just make the whole program setuid root (if you know what this sentence mean) and go ahead.  Or even better, do it as the root user, so you don't need to worry about setuid or the like.

Comment: Thanks for your concerns, but we need to write to /dev/mem to turn on/off a device. The function wasn't written by me but by who designed the board where the device is connected on, so he know what he do. And we don't have alternatives.
As suggested by other, I will try to use seteuid() function to change privileges after open /dev/mem as root.

Comment: @CDF, then probably it is better to use `/dev/kmem` which maps to the kernel virtual memory space.  That way, you can use the kernel memory map and don't have to translate yourself.  Anyway, a simple device development would be a better solution, as the way you proceed, there's no chance to be able to block or to impede simultaneous access to the same place, and crashing the whole system.  I think you don't know what you are planning.... a device driver would be the solution for that purpose.

Comment: I forward to the developer your suggestion to use /dev/kmem, thanks.

Comment: No, my suggestion was not to use `/dev/kmem`, but to write a driver... drivers are the only things to control devices..... if you try to control it by writing to `/dev/kmem` you will crash the thing also.... `/dev/kmem` is strongly deprecated to use.  Please, never say I have recommended to use `/dev/kmem` to stop a device... I have never done that.  And also, why is not the developer who asks the questions.  Do you feel you are needed in between?

Comment: Long story *very very* short (because comments have a limitation of characters): hardware/library people here are good on hardware/kernel/devices stuffs but are not good about security issues. I am the "last guy" hired and before my arrive they usually used to executed *all* the software by root (yeah, I known: do you remember the part where I say that they aren't good on security?). So I am trying to hardening the system. Oh, and I don't mentioned other constraint that don't allow us to do it in a different way.

Comment: So, please, stay on topic: the thread IS NOT about if it is a good or bad idea to write on /dev/mem, but about how to write to /dev/mem by unprivileged user. The answear is "NOT directly", but as suggested by Bjorn, I can start the program as root, open the file and than change the effective user id.